Found this apple-like plant in Denmark
I have found this apple-like fruit in Denmark. It was growing on a small tree, did some research and it looks similar to crab apple but it might not be it, can you help me confirm or deny that?




Need to see the tree it came from and the foliage to determine what it is

Unfortunately, I didn't take a photo and I am no longer there. But it was a little plant, maybe it was just young, I don't know. It was less than human-size, inside of the fruit is exactly like apple.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quince ?

@GiacomoCatenazzi Are there any quince with red skin?  I thought they only ever turned red when you cooked them.

@MackM: I do not think so, but I'm lost. Why do you think the fruits are red? (we have no picture). Apple and crab apple may be yellow and green. We lack picture to tell something useful (IMHO)

@MackM: Ah... I see only 3 line of text about picture and no pictures. Possibly an anti-meta filter on my side: it never failed so strongly

Yes. Definitely not a quince (and you are not a mentalist (or maybe you are) ;-) )

I am very startled to see 1) three people thought this question - how can you positively identify a suspected apple fruit - was not answerable even without images, and 2) that even so they were wrong as they missed the images Georgi uploaded, but voted to close anyway

What can you recall about the tree?  Leaf shape? Thorns?  How were the fruits growing, singly or in clusters (of many fruits or a few)?  Did you take pictures of the inside (and any pips)?

I'm not sure about the 'apple' shape - the dimple in the flower end (?) is right but the raised bit at the stem end less so.  That said, the crab apples Malus 'admiration' and 'red sentinel' are pretty close

Cut it in half (at equator if you treat the stem/blossom as the poles) and post that picture.

Your images look like a small apple to me too, and although there are lots of fruits that look like apples on the outside, I can't think of any that look quite the same on the inside.  Some ideas to confirm your apple suspicion:

If you plant a seed from the fruit, does an apple plant grow?
Does the fruit smell like a crabapple?
Does the fruit taste like a crabapple?
If you cut the fruit in half, does it have carpals holding seeds in that classic 3, 4, or 5 pointed symmetry?


